# Laravel 4 sending mails with plain php mail function

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In a few tutorials I have read that you can send emails with plain php `mail()` function. If I configure it with driver as `'mail'`. I do not receive any mail in my inbox of my google mail account, but I configured it to `receiver = googlemail-account`.

Instead of sending mails they will collected in

```
{ROOT_LARAVEL_FOLDER}/mailoutput/mail_{timestamp}.txt.
```

Can you give me an advise to solve that problem?

Comment: check if `app/config/mail.php` `pretend` isn't set to `true`

Comment: its false! i already checked it ;)

Comment: Do you by chance have different configs for different environments set up?

Comment: is your server itself configured to be able to send mail?

Comment: I dont know what I need to the server itself...what should I do to configure this server?

Comment: @GeorgeKrause check your php.ini;

Comment: Do i need it to configure it with smtp?

Comment: There you'll find my php.ini http://pastebin.com/QYwi3kPj